# Cake PHP drop down list

Tags: list, cakephp

I would like to know how to add a drop down list for "access control" with value "staff" and "Admin".
This is my add function in employee controller

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Employee->create();
            if ($this->Employee->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The employee has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The employee could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the add view code:

```
<div class="employees form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Employee'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Employee Details'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('date_hired', array('dateFormat' => 'DMY','minYear'=>date('Y')-100, 'maxYear'=>date('Y')+100));
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_phone_number');
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_email');
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_address');
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_dob', array('dateFormat' => 'DMY','minYear'=>date('Y')-100, 'maxYear'=>date('Y')+100));
        echo $this->Form->input('access_level');
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_username');
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_pw');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use an [enum like approach](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/) for example - using class constants.

Comment: Read the documentation on the [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs), it has your answers.

Answer (score 2):

To add a drop down list for `access control` with value `staff` and `Admin`. 
add this in your employee controller

```
$customers = $this->Employee->modelname->find('list');
$this->set(compact('customers'));
```

and  in `view.ctp`

```
echo $this->Form->input('access_level');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting access_level data from database then-

```
 echo $this->Form->input('access_level', array('options' => array('admin' => 'Admin', 'staff' => 'Ataff')));
```